# Can a git pre-push hook warn me if my current branch's source code contains a string?

Tags: git, github, hook, githooks

I frequently forget to remove debugging code (like `console.log()` from my `git` branches before they are reviewed. I'm ok with *committing* the `console.log()` calls, *as long as* I remember to remove them before squashing and merging the branch.

I'm wondering how to write a pre-push hook that will check whether any `console.log()` calls are retained in my current branch. I don't want the hook to block me from merging, but rather just to remind me to remove those lines of code. Can a pre-push hook do this?

Comment: I've used a combination of `husky` and `eslint` to do this - pre-commit hook runs lint, lint rule forbids use of console.

Comment: Please don't put meta content in questions - self-answered questions are fine, but both Q & A must meet the usual standards.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting a `pre-push` hook working (installed in `.git/hooks/pre-push`, and having run `chmod +x` on it):

(Please consider this Public Domain, via a [CC0 dedication](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/).)

```
echo "Running pre-push hook..."

# Grep below should match the following cases from git diff:
    # +++ testserver.js
    # +console.log(djsdlkjd)
    # + ... console.log(djsdlkjd)
# For an explanation of the regex, see
# https://regex101.com/r/92ysUf/1
searchOutput=$(git --no-pager diff -G"console.log" master...HEAD | perl -ne'print if m{^(\+{1}|\+{3})(?!\+)( |.*?\bconsole.log)}')

# If $searchOutput is blank, wc -l will show it as having 1 line.
# Thus, we will check below whether it has >1 line, and, if so,
# print it and a warning.
if [ $(echo "$searchOutput" | wc -l) -gt 1 ]
then
    echo "\n----------------\n"
    echo "WARNING: The branch you are pushing contains at least one added console.log(). Here is the abbreviated git diff output:\n"
    echo "$searchOutput"
    echo "\nContinuing with the push; you may want to remove the lines above in a future commit, though."
    echo "\n----------------\n"
fi

exit
```

This will now remind me every time I push if (and where) there are `console.log` calls remaining in my current branch.

I'm posting this answer because it might help future readers understand not only how to accomplish this, but also how to search the source code of a current `git` branch.

Comment: Instead of `git --no-pager diff ...` consider running one of the diff plumbing commands, in this case `git diff-tree`. You'll need options, particularly `-r`. Also, consider using `git rev-list` to find all the commits, not just the two identified by `master` and `HEAD`, reading stdin to find which commits are actually going to get pushed based on what the remote hash ID is and what your replacement local hash ID is.